# Bringing out the numbers from a list that are smaller than an integer/float

Tags: python

I have to make a program in Python 3.4 that let's me input numbers and names that go into a list, and then I have print out the numbers that are less than average of the sum. I've been stuck with the last part as I don't know how to print out only the numbers that are less than average of the list. 
Let's say the list is [190, 188, 185, 174, 172] and the average is 181.8, how can I get it working?

//edit I got the first part working with this

> `uus_list = []`
>
> > `for x in pikkused:`
> >
> > > `for y in kesk_list:`
> > >
> > > > `if x < y:`
> > > >         `uus_list.append(x))`

However, I got another problem. Is there a way to tie 2 lists together?

Comment: Since this is probably a homework assignment I don't want to do it for you. But assuming you know the average already, I suggest looking into [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and their built in filtering abilities. Or if you're feeling functional, the [filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) method

Answer (score 0):

```
num = [190, 188, 185, 174, 172]
avg = sum(num)/len(num)
[ x for x in num if x < avg ]
```

here in my code `sum` function will give you sum of all element of list num. `len` will give you no of element in num.

Comment: Sadly you have just done someones how work for him - how will they learn if they just come here and get someone else to do it for them ?

Comment: sorry yeaa they need to try and give what they have tried